# SQL: группировка данных

Tags: sql

Есть табличка

```
code  idArt idManufact
0001  222   1
0002  223   1
0003  222   1
0001  333   2
0002  334   2
0003  335   2
0004  333   2
```

Нужно получить все значения  в рамках `idManufact`
где `idArt` <> `idArt`  c `code = 0001`, а так же исключить все  `idArt`  c `code = 0001`
т.е. получить нужно:

```
code  idArt idManufact
0002  223   1
0002  334   2
0003  335   2
```

Comment: объясните еще раз, что исключить. то что `where code <> '001'` понятно. с остальным что?

Comment: `where idArt not in(select idArt from tab where code='0001'`) но что означает 'в рамках idManufact' совершенно не ясно, в результате у вас он встречается несколько раз

Comment: по каждому idManufact есть ряд code  и idArt. Вот нужно  чтобы для каждого idManufact вычислялись те  idArt, что не совпадают с idArt где  code='0001'. Один поставщик idManufact, у него несколько моделей idArt  с  разными кодами. Вот нужно для каждого поставщика определить все его модели которые не совпадают сего же  моделью с кодом 0001.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

что-то вроде такого видимо должно быть?

```
SELECT a.*
FROM data AS a
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT idArt, idMan
     FROM data 
     WHERE code = '0001' 
  ) AS b ON (a.idMan = b.idMan and a.idArt  = b.idArt)    
WHERE b.idArt is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, что понял ваш запрос целиком, но как-то так работает:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM s
 WHERE idart NOT IN (
  SELECT idart
    FROM s
   WHERE code = '0001'
)
;
```

*DB Fiddle*:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pXPcMHcSYxSnZYKp28qxng/0.